# How should I remotely query a local MySQL database through my hosted php script?

Tags: mysql, php

I would like to access a local MySQL database through my PHP script hosted on a remote server. Is there a way to code a script, that I save on the local machine, and receives queries from my remote PHP script, executes, and the results are submitted back to the script?

How is this technology called?

I know, that I could just open the MySQL port on my firewall, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: This is a PHP programming question and not related to database administration. Please delete it here and repost on StackOverflow.

Comment: You are after a service layer, see this link  for an introduction to PHP services. Try to get a simple service working and repost on StackOverflow if you get stuck.

Comment: @Jaco - you forgot to paste in the link URL.

Comment: Sorry, this was the link: http://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-services/

Comment: If you are sending HTTP requests, you need a "web server" such as Apache.  If you simply need to query a remote MySQL database, then it needs to GRANT your host access; no need for the extra Apache+PHP hop.

Comment: That link seems to be "overkill".